# I need help moving 2 objects freely in Processing, making pong

Tags: processing

Its bad code but only because its a test, but if you could help thatll be great
heres my code:

```
float x = 100;
float y = 260;
float y2 = 265;
float x2 = 600;

void setup() {
  size(750,750);
}

void draw() {
background(167);
  rect(x,y,15,75);
  rect(x2,y2,15,75);
  
  if (keyPressed == true) {
    if(key == 'w' || key == 'W') {
      y = y - 10;
    }
    if(key == 's' || key == 'S') {
      y = y + 10;
    }
    if(key == 'o' || key == 'O') {
      y2 = y2 - 10;
    }
    if(key == 'l' || key == 'L') {
      y2 = y2 + 10;
    }
  }
}
```

moving one will make the other pause, and id like them to both move

Answer (score 0):

The following source code uses a boolean array to keep track of the keyPresses/Releases of the four keys and will allow simultaneous trapping of presses:

```
boolean[] keyDwn = new boolean[4];

final int _keyW = 87;
final int _keyS = 83;
final int _keyO = 79;
final int _keyL = 76;

float x = 100;
float y = 260;
float y2 = 265;
float x2 = 600;

void setup() {
  size(750, 750);
}

void draw() {
  background(167);
  // W
  if (keyDwn[0] == true) {
    y = y - 10;
  }
  // S
  if (keyDwn[1] == true) {
    y = y + 10;
  }
  // O
  if (keyDwn[2] == true) {
    y2 = y2 - 10;
  }
  // L
  if (keyDwn[3] == true) {
    y2 = y2 + 10;
  }
  rect(x, y, 15, 75);
  rect(x2, y2, 15, 75);
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode == _keyW) {
    keyDwn[0] = true;
    println("keyF pressed = ", keyCode);
  }
  if (keyCode == _keyS) {
    keyDwn[1] = true;
    println("keyJ pressed = ", keyCode);
  }
  if (keyCode == _keyO) {
    keyDwn[2] = true;
    println("keyJ pressed = ", keyCode);
  }
  if (keyCode == _keyL) {
    keyDwn[3] = true;
    println("keyJ pressed = ", keyCode);
  }
}

void keyReleased() {
  if (keyCode == _keyW) {
    keyDwn[0] = false;
  }
  if (keyCode == _keyS) {
    keyDwn[1] = false;
  }
  if (keyCode == _keyO) {
    keyDwn[2] = false;
  }
  if (keyCode == _keyL) {
    keyDwn[3] = false;
  }
}
```